# Why does $ echo "Testing" | write user pts/0 | at now + 1 min execute instantly?

Tags: linux, bash, manjaro, at

I want to integrate the at command into a script, but that script is reliant upon the write command executing at the right time. So far, every time I try to do this, it just writes instantly, not at the time I schedule.

```
$ echo "Testing" | write user pts/0 | at now + 1 min
```

or

```
$ write user pts/0 | at 18:30
```

Both execute immediately, not at the scheduled time.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're piping the *output of the write command* to `at`, not *giving* `at` the write command. Try:

```bsh
at now + 1 min << 'END_AT'
echo "Testing" | write user pts/0 
END_AT
```